# Omitting Numeric Literal Types from number type while type still being reconised as a number?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I found that you can omit a number literal union from a number type to allow you to input any number but still get type hints from my number literal union type. The only problem is that this type is no longer recongised as a number. Is there any sort of typescript magic I can use to make typescript recognise it as a valid number type again?

```
type S = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
type T = S | Omit<number, S>

// Still get type hints for S while still being able to put any number
const a: T = 3;

function test(num: number){
  return num;
}

test(a); //Error, type not assignable to type number
```

Comment: Using `Omit<number, S>` does not make any sense. What are you trying to achieve? Please keep in mind, that it makes sense to use `Omit<number, 'toFixed'>`, because second argument of `Omit` should be name of property.

Comment: [The `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) does not work the way you think it does, and so `Omit<number, S>` is bizarre and you should not do it.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question; instead of `Omit<number, S>` you can use `(number & {})` to get the desired behavior, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9EV9N).

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks 